# HTML5 Datalist dropdown preventing Enter from propagating in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using HTML5 datalist. When user selects an option in the dropdown. **On pressing enter on dropdown option** -  i need to perform an action. It works fine in `Firefox` and `IE` but in `Chrome` I don't receive the enter event.

Any workaround?

https://jsfiddle.net/34va7w1g/

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score -2):

Try using 'which' and 'keyCode':

```
function doStuff (event) {
if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    //code to execute here
    return false;
}
return true;
};
```

If you don't know what to do with this, here is an example:

```
<datalist onkeydown="doStuff(e)">
```

Note: Key Code number 13 is the Enter Key.

Comment: select and datalist are different

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? It works fine for me in Chrome 43.

Comment: @ user2072826 Chrome 43 - you are not getting it, enter on dropdown option is blocking enter key and not the input